# Notes on MacOS Sierra

Tags: mac, icloud, backup, notes.app, macos

I just upgraded to MacOS Sierra and I lost a week-long of notes in Notes. It happened, after I restored a backup from a week ago and then installed Sierra. All my notes sync with iCloud, but there simply aren't any notes now from since last week. 
Is there any kind of way to recover those notes, because they are reaaaaaally important to me...
Thanks:)

Comment: Can you check on [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/#notes2) to see if they are there?

Comment: I already checked. No luck there, even in the restore section. :/

Answer (score 4):

No.  They are gone.  iCloud, for a lack of a better word is a "sync conduit" *between* your devices; it's not a backup.    This means that a change you make on any of your devices is what gets synced.

When you restored the 1 week old backup from Time Machine, more than likely, Notes did a sync which overwrote what was on iCloud because it "assumed" that was the latest data to be synced.

What you should do in the future....***prior to upgrading your OS*** do a manual Time Machine backup so it saves the latest state. This way you **know** for a fact that what you restore is your most recent version.

Comment: Thank you - that's my explanation as well. Sadly, I have overwritten the notes and even when entering TimeMachine when offline, and restoring them manually from the Notes folder in Library, still no success. If anyone can come up with some kind of a workaround, it'd be a lifesaver, but I doubt it it's possible :/

Answer (score -1):

Restore a more recent TM backup, and your notes will be fine again !!